# Trying to calculate an essential matrix using skimage, or cv2

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I am trying to understand how to work with cv2.findEssentialMat or skimage variant. I have a known 3d model in world coordinates and two calibrated cameras. I computed the true essential matrix of the system and my goal is to project the known 3d model points into each of the cameras and use cv2 (or skimage) to recover the known essential matrix.

The essential matrix is computed from the image correspondences because the 3d structure isnt known. If it is known then it is simply I can simply compute the relative pose between the cameras as `∆E=E_r @ E_l^-1` and then compute the essential matrix. `E=T_x @ R` where `@` a is matrix multiplication, `T_x` is the matrix associated with the normalized translation vector and `R` is the rotation matrix.

After I confirm that my calculations are good, I project the world points into each camera and use `cv2.findEssentialMat` to compute the essential matrix from the image coordinates. I expect the essential matrix thatI calculated to be the same as the one from `cv2.findEssentialMat`. Yet the two are very different.
Does anyone know what I am missing?

Here is my setup

```
def apply_rt(pts, rt):
    return (rt[:3, :3] @ pts.T).T + rt[:3, -1]

def project_points(xyzs, intrinsic, extrinsic, should_normalize=False):
    projected_points_cr = (intrinsic @ apply_rt(xyzs, extrinsic).T).T
    divisors = projected_points_cr[:, 2:]
    projected_points_cr = projected_points_cr / divisors
    if should_normalize:
        projected_points_cr = (np.linalg.inv(intrinsic) @ projected_points_cr.T).T
    return projected_points_cr[:, :2]

xyzs_world = np.array([
       [73.008575, 52.755592, 39.83713 ],
       [72.075424, 47.25908 , 40.036087],
       [72.20231 , 45.843777, 40.351246],
       [73.43591 , 54.131153, 39.584625],
       [74.108826, 44.653885, 42.031307],
       [77.388   , 49.497707, 42.064713],
       [77.185585, 48.65105 , 42.162895],
       [77.388245, 43.62944 , 42.370674],
       [77.02157 , 53.728027, 41.259354],
       [74.88333 , 54.320747, 40.528275],
       [76.66945 , 43.3657  , 42.48002 ],
       [71.57631 , 51.054092, 38.390312],
       [71.905975, 52.52903 , 38.386307],
       [72.099724, 48.342022, 39.933678],
       [73.300545, 45.25413 , 41.518044],
       [75.36074 , 54.748974, 40.528008],
       [74.20519 , 53.809402, 40.38417 ],
       [74.10402 , 48.007614, 41.790726],
       [71.70616 , 48.58014 , 39.25619 ],
       [77.78094 , 45.657528, 42.211655],
       [74.894455, 44.303238, 42.315697],
       [72.35703 , 51.532913, 39.52483 ],
       [77.83151 , 53.58341 , 41.273026],
       [73.03928 , 51.10847 , 40.470455],
       [77.50123 , 48.578613, 42.125782],
       [74.307816, 55.139206, 39.728397],
       [74.199196, 48.10794 , 41.825573],
       [72.19932 , 50.435875, 39.648094],
       [71.919846, 45.61991 , 39.96143 ],
       [77.08149 , 43.011536, 42.4573  ],
       [76.36457 , 46.383766, 42.35271 ],
       [74.79315 , 48.619663, 41.99683 ],
       [74.39389 , 52.70309 , 40.95705 ],
       [73.83906 , 44.51386 , 41.910065],
       [72.639786, 44.48964 , 40.993587],
       [75.381966, 45.770576, 42.32749 ],
       [78.57214 , 47.213417, 41.966934],
       [77.5113  , 46.790035, 42.220528],
       [73.846436, 46.48003 , 41.783493],
       [74.31437 , 53.745804, 40.484417],
       [74.80585 , 44.500835, 42.28195 ],
       [76.932724, 42.753857, 42.496098],
       [74.27546 , 47.899445, 41.879692],
       [71.30465 , 45.965378, 38.79394 ],
       [78.21704 , 43.769154, 42.18486 ],
       [76.79267 , 52.646767, 41.56925 ],
       [72.67541 , 54.200233, 38.643562],
       [78.73034 , 50.631893, 41.681744],
       [74.487144, 51.408913, 41.39855 ],
       [74.22435 , 51.41863 , 41.266033]], dtype=np.float32)

intrinsics_right = np.array([
       [2549.682106, 0.000000, 1193.621053],
       [0.000000, 2588.379958, 632.521320],
       [0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000]])
intrinsics_left = np.array([
       [2514.183473, 0.000000, 1421.766881],
       [0.000000, 2530.292937, 1017.599687],
       [0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000]])

extrinsics_right = np.array([
        [0.908730, 0.031275, -0.416211, -52.430834],
        [-0.046736, -0.983293, -0.175928, 50.173038],
        [-0.414760, 0.179323, -0.892086, 179.569364],
        [0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000]])

extrinsics_left = np.array([
        [0.908264, -0.017047, 0.418049, -66.914767],
        [-0.008166, -0.999702, -0.023024, 22.166049],
        [0.418317, 0.017498, -0.908133, 130.945395],
        [0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000]])

rel_pose = extrinsics_right @ np.linalg.inv(extrinsics_left)
X_r = apply_rt(xyzs_world, extrinsics_right)
X_l = apply_rt(xyzs_world, extrinsics_left)

essential_gt = T_x @ rel_pose[:3,:3]
# result is:
# np.array([[0.005759, -0.415231, -0.020870],
#       [-0.415659, -0.153303, 0.895284],
#       [0.059779, -0.896665, -0.147390]])

epipolar_constraint = np.linalg.norm(np.einsum('ij,ij->i', X_r, (essential_gt @ X_l.T).T))
print(epipolar_constraint) # print 1e-11
```

This value of `epipolar_constraint` is around `1e-11` indicating the calculations are good. For the next stage, I will project the world points into each camera and in this way, I have corresponding image points. Then I call `cv2.findEssentialMat`. Following the instructions in the opencv docs I normlize the image coordinates and pass the identity in place of the extrinsics because I have two different cameras.

```
rcs_l = project_points(xyzs_world, intrinsics_left, extrinsics_left, should_normalize=True)
rcs_r = project_points(xyzs_world, intrinsics_right, extrinsics_right, should_normalize=True)
essential, inliers = cv2.findEssentialMat(rcs_l, rcs_r, np.eye(3))
# result is 
# np.array([[-0.000108, 0.000701, -0.394863],
#       [-0.000634, 0.000407, -0.586585],
#       [0.423443, 0.566300, 0.000232]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing in the same vein it turns out the `essential` also satisfies the epipolar constraint, both on the image points and on the 3d points. It turns out that the two matrices are the same up to a scale. They differ only in the singular values of their respective SVD's. Decomposing `essential` into its rotation and translation components and multiplying back again `T_x, R = decompose(essential)` and then taking `np.linalg.norm(T_x@R - essential_gt)≈≈0`